# RichFaces 4 - how to disable skins

Tags: themes, richfaces, skinning, skins

Is there any way how to disable all skins RichFaces apply? They ruin my layout and override fonts, links,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine each CSS style, but it'll be boring...
Have a look at [reset css](http://cssresetr.com/), this can help you to redefine the CSS.

or, you can try to remove style:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>disable</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_CLASSES</param-name>
    <param-value>disable</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or try to use the plain style

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
  <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: i suggest looking at the solution of cristan, basically skin 'plain' will not erase all skins, but enableControlSkinning seems to erase all skins

Answer (score 14):

In RichFaces 4.1 you can disable skinning by adding the following to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

(I found this and other parameters at http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/javadoc/richfaces-core-impl/org/richfaces/application/CoreConfiguration.Items.html)

Comment: Well I missread your post. I'd suggest remove the sentence about enableControlSkinningClasses, it mislead into thinking you refer enableControlSkinning. I'll delete my post because it is missleading as well. I only wanted to say that your answer is the only one working. Chaning a skin (like suggested somewhere else) to PLAIN doesn't resolve all problems. But your solution seems to work fine.