# Disable skinning for one page

Tags: richfaces, skinning

I know I can disable skinning of all RichFaces pages in web.xml from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615321/1015595).

However, I would like to disable skinning for a single page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can change theme on the fly, you can simulate this action during load your single page and rollback to regular theme for other pages.

Comment: For inspiration see comment in [How to replace the value of skin parameter on the fly in Richfaces 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415690/how-to-replace-the-value-of-skin-parameter-on-the-fly-in-richfaces-4-3)